# P&T Fieldpack:Checkbox - Spitting out if conditional instead of parsing it

Tags: pixelandtonic, conditionals, pt-checkboxes

I am running into a problem with the fieldpack checkbox on a site I am developing.

I am using the following code inside an {exp:channel:entries} loop, but the first two entries is echoing out the if conditional as seen below.

Channel entries loop: {exp:channel:entries channel="stories" orderby="entry_date" sort="desc" limit="20"}

if conditional:

```
{if "{story_type:selected option='Video'}"}
    <span class="prl-overlay-area o-video"></span>
{/if}
{if '{story_type:selected option="Audio"}'}
    <span class="prl-overlay-area o-video"></span>
{/if}
```

What the page shows:

[image]

as seen here: http://new.danaloeschradio.com/ (below the gunbox ad).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured it out.  For reference in the future.

Here was the culprit:

```
{exp:ce_str:ing remove_html substr="0|150" xss_clean}
```

specifically, "substr".  This method of ce_string and P&T Fieldpack did not play nice together on the same page.  I fixed it by using the following alternative method.

```
{exp:ce_str:ing remove_html truncate="150|..." xss_clean}
```